# no matching function for call to xxx in Hash Table Separate Chaining

Tags: c++, algorithm, hashtable, chaining

Currently I am  trying to convert the Binary Search Tree to Hash Table with Separate Chaining algorithm for develop a simple program in DEV-C++.

So far, I've converted the insert,delete,search and display operation function, along with hash function.

**item list.txt:**

```
    Item ID  Item Price Item Name
    10001     23.00     Book1 
    10002     24.00     Book2
    10003     31.98     Book3
    10004     41.90     Book4
```

The part that I'm stuck is I don't know **how to insert** all items of **item list.txt** into the hash table.

**function to hash text file data:**

```
void fillHashTable(HashTableSeparateChaining hashtable){
ifstream file;
file.open("item list.txt");
if(!file) {
    cout<<" Error opening file. " << endl;}

int item_id;
double price;
string item_name;

Item i;
struct node* A[M];

while(file >> item_id >> price >> item_name)
{
    i.setItem_id(item_id);
    i.setPrice(price);
    i.setItem_name(item_name);

    HashTableSeparateChaining hashtable;
    int hv = hash_function( i.getItem_id());       

    hashtable.insert(&A[hv], &A[hv], i);
}
file.close();}
```

**class HashTableSeparateChaining:**

```
class HashTableSeparateChaining{
  private:
          struct node
          {
                 struct node *next;//SINGLY-LINKED LIST
                 struct node *prev;
                 Item data;
          };

  public:

        void insert(struct node **h, struct node **t, Item i);
        void Delete(struct node **h, struct node **t, int i);
        void display( struct node* h );
        void search( struct node *h, int key );                          
};
```

**insert method:**

```
void HashTableSeparateChaining::insert(struct node **h, struct node **t, Item i){
 struct node *n = new node;

if( *h == NULL ) {
    n->data = i;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->prev = NULL;
    *h = n;
    *t = n;
} else {
    n->data = i;
    n->next = *h;
    n->next->prev = n;
    n->prev = NULL;
    *h = n;
    }}
```

**main:**

```
int main(){
...
struct node* A[M];

bool b;

for( i = 0; i < M; i++ ) {
    A[i] = NULL;
}
fillHashTable(hashtable);
.....
   //I allow user to make insert/delete element to the existing **item.list.text**
```

So after I run this program, I expect that I can display all the existing data from **item list.tx**t and the data already being hashed. Then user can make insertion or deletion to that text file.

So far, I've got this **error** when try to compile.

> no matching function for call to
>   `HashTableSeparateChaining::insert(node**, node**, Item&)'

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? Is that the only output from the compiler?

Comment: What is`Item` type ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Error at `hashtable.insert(&A[hv], &A[hv], i);` . Output of program is depends on user option. Eg: Enter 1 for insert, 2 for delete, 3 for display

Comment: @Jerome Item is an object which have item_id, price and item_name

Comment: @doraemon check if this class have a public copy constructor

Comment: Not output from the program, from the *compiler* when you build. Because e.g. GCC and Clang would show more informational output and not just that single line.

Comment: `node` is private local struct of `HashTableSeparateChaining` class so you shouldn't be able to use it outside of this class like in 3rd snippet. Begin your fixes with moving it outside or make `public` and refer via `HashTableSeparateChaining::node`

Comment: @Glapa Your are right, all the `struct node*` hide the previous error

Comment: Whats more `fillHashTable` should look like this: `fillHashTable(HashTableSeparateChaining& hashtable)` if you want to have original (from main) `hashtable` variable modified.

Comment: And why do you create `hashtable` inside the loop there?

Comment: @Glapa Because this hash table is a list of array with M-1 size where each array holds a pointer (linked list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After compiling your code with some fixes I'm sure that problem is private `node` struct. Compiler error that clarifies everything:

```
25:6: note: void HashTableSeparateChaining::insert(HashTableSeparateChaining::node**, HashTableSeparateChaining::node**, Item)
25:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'fillHashTable(HashTableSeparateChaining)::node**' to 'HashTableSeparateChaining::node**'
```

As I already stated beafore in comment `node` is private local struct of `HashTableSeparateChaining` class so you shouldn't be able to use it outside of this class like in 3rd snippet. Begin your fixes with moving it outside or make public and refer via `HashTableSeparateChaining::node`. It will fix this one problem. But there is more. `fillHashTable` does not take argument by reference and creates local `hashtable` variables inside loop. IMHO that code should look like this:

```
void fillHashTable(HashTableSeparateChaining& hashtable){
ifstream file;
file.open("item list.txt");
if(!file) {
    cout<<" Error opening file. " << endl;}

int item_id;
double price;
string item_name;

Item i;
struct node* A[M];

while(file >> item_id >> price >> item_name)
{
    i.setItem_id(item_id);
    i.setPrice(price);
    i.setItem_name(item_name);

   int hv = hash_function( i.getItem_id());       
   hashtable.insert(&A[hv], &A[hv], i);
}
file.close();}
```

Classes:

```
struct node
{
      struct node *next;//SINGLY-LINKED LIST
      struct node *prev;
      Item data;
};

class HashTableSeparateChaining{
public:

    void insert(struct node **h, struct node **t, Item i);
    void Delete(struct node **h, struct node **t, int i);
    void display( struct node* h );
    void search( struct node *h, int key );                          
};
```